# Why I can't compile this simple Java Code on CMD, but compile it on an online compiler?

Tags: java, cmd, compilation

I have this Java code from a book (named Schaum's Outline of Principles of Computer Science):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

        y=7;
        z=4;
        x=y+z;
        System.out.println("x = "+x);
    }
}
```

I have changed "Primitive" to "Main". And it can be compiled at this website:

http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Output is just "x = 11".

But when trying to compile it using CMD on Windows 8.1 using `javac Main.java` I got this error message (the filename is Main.java):

```
Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 ■p u b l i c   c l a s s   M a i n {
               ^
Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 ■p u b l i c   c l a s s   M a i n {
                           ^
Main.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
 ■p u b l i c   c l a s s   M a i n {
                                    ^
Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 ■p u b l i c   c l a s s   M a i n {
                                     ^
Main.java:2: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
              ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                            ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                      ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal start of type
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                               ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                              ^
Main.java:3: error: ';' expected
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                               ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                                ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal start of type
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                                         ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                                          ^
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 p u b l i c   s t a t i c   v o i d   m a i n ( S t r i n g [ ] a r g s ) {
                                                                            ^
Main.java:4: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:5: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   x ;
^
Main.java:5: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   x ;
        ^
Main.java:5: error: not a statement
 i n t   x ;
 ^
Main.java:5: error: not a statement
 i n t   x ;
         ^
Main.java:5: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   x ;
            ^
Main.java:6: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:7: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   y ;
^
Main.java:7: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   y ;
        ^
Main.java:7: error: not a statement
 i n t   y ;
 ^
Main.java:7: error: not a statement
 i n t   y ;
         ^
Main.java:7: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   y ;
            ^
Main.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:9: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   z ;
^
Main.java:9: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   z ;
        ^
Main.java:9: error: not a statement
 i n t   z ;
 ^
Main.java:9: error: not a statement
 i n t   z ;
         ^
Main.java:9: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 i n t   z ;
            ^
Main.java:10: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:11: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:12: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:13: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 y = 7 ;
^
Main.java:13: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 y = 7 ;
    ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 y = 7 ;
      ^
Main.java:13: error: not a statement
 y = 7 ;
     ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 y = 7 ;
        ^
Main.java:14: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 z = 4 ;
^
Main.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 z = 4 ;
    ^
Main.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 z = 4 ;
      ^
Main.java:15: error: not a statement
 z = 4 ;
     ^
Main.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 z = 4 ;
        ^
Main.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 x = y + z ;
^
Main.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 x = y + z ;
    ^
Main.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 x = y + z ;
        ^
Main.java:17: error: not a statement
 x = y + z ;
       ^
Main.java:17: error: not a statement
 x = y + z ;
         ^
Main.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 x = y + z ;
            ^
Main.java:18: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
              ^
Main.java:19: error: not a statement
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
             ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                      ^
Main.java:19: error: not a statement
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                     ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                      ^
Main.java:19: error: ';' expected
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                       ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                  ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                    ^
Main.java:19: error: not a statement
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                   ^
Main.java:19: error: not a statement
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                     ^
Main.java:19: error: ';' expected
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                       ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                        ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 S y s t e m . o u t . p r i n t l n ( " x   =   " + x ) ;
                                                          ^
Main.java:20: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:21: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 }
^
Main.java:21: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 }
  ^
Main.java:22: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

^
Main.java:23: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 }
^
Main.java:23: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
 }
  ^
Main.java:23: error: reached end of file while parsing
 }
   ^
78 errors
```

Even when I remove all the spaces, I get 35 errors.

The Java Versions I have installed are:
Java 8 Update 60 (64-bit) (I have Windows 64-bits)
Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 60 (64 bit)
Both versions are 8.0.600.27

**Why I can't compile on CMD?** Is it because I use Notepad 6.3 (the standard Notepad that are included on Windows 8.1 and other versions)?

Comment: Looks like your Notepad adds this empty (0) character to your file. I recommend you using another text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime to clear the file from these characters.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you've copy/pasted this code from somewhere, and the encoding is messed up.

Comment: Did you copy and paste it directly from the website? If so, try typing it out in notepad. If you wish to write Java on your computer, I recommend installing an IDE such as NetBeans.

Comment: Download a modern IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans...it will make your life 1000 times easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You file was saved in UTF-16, but you didn't tell the compiler that (`-encoding`).

Suggest you open the file in Notepad and save it again in the default code page of your system.

Comment: There are ANSI, Unicode, Unicode Big Endian and UTF-8. Should I save it using ANSI?

Comment: That would be best, yeah.